# Trying to embed a video to my Github repo's README.md file

Tags: github, markdown

Im trying to embed a video to my github repo's README.md. When dragging and dropping, github generates something like

https://github.com/rayytsn9/ROBOTT/assets/79029536/62f541aa-aa8c-43f5-9ead-4b7a2e0d7c2a

instead of something like

https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/...

as mentioned from the posts regarding embedding a video to README from other threads. In the previews, the videos look fine but once I have deployed the site, the website doesnt display the video at all, only the link "https://github.com/rayytsn9/ROBOTT/assets/79029536/62f541aa-aa8c-43f5-9ead-4b7a2e0d7c2a". Any advise would be appreciated. Thanks in advance!!

Aside from that Im very clueless as to what to do to fix this problem since the preview looks fine.

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to embed a .webm video on GitHub but it only worked after converting the video to .mp4

Answer (score 0):

You can use that https://github.com/rayytsn9/ROBOTT/assets/79029536/62f541aa-aa8c-43f5-9ead-4b7a2e0d7c2a as well. But you need to add the `<video />` element around it. For example:

```
<video src="https://github.com/rayytsn9/ROBOTT/assets/79029536/62f541aa-aa8c-43f5-9ead-4b7a2e0d7c2a" width="300" />
```

Change the width to whatever you prefer. Without a defined width, it seems to use `100%`, which may not be what you want (eg. a 1920x1080 video would appear at full size).